# Is it a good idea to add a booking flow inside of a bottom sheet modal

Tags: modal, booking

I decided to include a booking flow inside of a [bottom sheet modal](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) so that the user doesn't need to leave the practitioner's profile to book an appointment with them. Is this okay?

Comment: Hard to say without a broader perspective of the user process. Does the [modal bottom sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) activation control interfere with the practitioner's profile page? Does the modal bottom sheet provide everything necessary for the user to make a booking? If no and yes, then why not?

Comment: If this step is a side-step, then I would consider using a bottom sheet modal, like sharing the info of the ticket with your partner/friends/family. If this step is in the process of completing it, then I would not suggest using the modal.

Answer (score 0):

"Why do the users need to stay on the practitioner's profile when booking an appointment?"

I think answering the above question would guide you in choosing the design. What information should be in front of users' eyes when they are booking an appointment?

Modal bottom sheets cover a good portion of the bottom part of the main content, so you obviously can't have the practitioner's available times there, for example.